# Keeping tables consistent during trigger execution?

Tags: oracle

I have a trigger that checks another couple of tables before allowing a row to be inserted. However between the time I check the other tables and insert the row the other tables may get updated.

How do I ensure the tables I'm checking remain in a consistent state until after the new row is inserted? I was thinking of taking locks out but everything I've read boils down to if you are *not* leaving locking to Oracle you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you describe the sorts of checks you are doing?  Depending on what you're doing, it may be appropriate to create constraints that enforce the checks, to move the checks to commit time with a materialized view, to serialize transactions by doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` or some other solution depending on the specifics of the problem.

Comment: It is also true that if you're using triggers to enforce relational integrity you're doing it wrong.  Ditto for business logic, except in certain very special cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle is already doing this for you, when you perform a select it will look at all tables as of the time the transaction started ( the time of the first DML ). This wont stop the data from being changed under you though, your transaction just wont see it being changed. If you want to stop that data from being changed then you can use "SELECT FOR UPDATE" as Justin Cave suggests.

I would seriously question what you are doing though, triggers, except in the most trivial cases, almost always lead to unexpected side effects.

Comment: Rather than use a trigger it looks like I should just use a standard procedure and just lock down access to the underlying tables. Thank you everyone.